# AngularJS, Materializecss: условие ng-if не убирает слайд с html документа

Tags: angularjs, materialize-css

Я использую [Materializecss Carousel](https://materializecss.com/carousel.html) для отображение слайдов. У каждого слайда, есть промежуток времени, в котором он отображается.

```
    $scope.videos = [
        {
            display: true,
            start: 'Jul 23 2019 00:00:01',
            end: 'Jul 25 2019 00:00:01',
            hours: '',
            minutes: '',
            seconds: ''
        },
        {
            display: false,
            start: 'Jul 24 2019 00:00:01',
            end: 'Jul 26 2019 00:00:01',
            hours: '',
            minutes: '',
            seconds: ''
        }].
```

Когда я ставлю условие ng-if = false,

```
<div class="carousel-item" ng-if="videos[1].display">1</div>
```

Слайдер отображается в виде пустого места, и он продолжает существовать в html документе. Мне необходимо убрать слайд с html документа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как временное решение, можно использовать setTimeout

```
    function initSlider() {
        $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
            fullWidth: true
        });
    }

    setTimeout(initSlider, 2000);
```